# Looking for a good user/group configuration for sites on apache httpd server

Tags: apache-2.2

we have a setup where various persons develop on their local machines, to later commit the changes to a local server repository.

In order to sync the changes to our external production server, we run a script which rsyncs a local subversion export to it.

We face a problem doing this sync, because in order to work, the user doing the sync on the remote server need to be the owner of the remote files.

Our solution was:

Create a user on the remote server (siteowner)
Giving him the ownership of the site (chown siteowner.siteowner /var/www/site)
Adding apache to the group of the siteowner (we had some problems with htaccess checks, and we can't chown siteowner.apache because when rsync does the sync it changes the permissions to siteowner.siteowner)

My question is... this setup seems reasonable? Do you know any other better one? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use the following workflow for our PHP based websites.

Users commit their work to Subversion. We *don't* allow developers to *manually* deploy code to Staging and Live. Why not to staging? Because we want it to closely simulate Live.
Deployments are done via [Webistrano](http://labs.peritor.com/webistrano), which is a web frontend to the well-known and powerful [Capistrano](http://www.capify.org/) deployment tool. We've created so-called recipes that script the deployment. It does approximately the following:

- Webistrano logs into the server via ssh as user 'deploy'
- It updates a remote working-copy cache
- It copies the resulting working-copy to a releases// folder, using hardlinks (to save diskspace and for speed).
- Symlinks customer-data (i.e. files not stored in subversion) to the proper locations.
- The new release is chmodded to 775 to give the group write permissions.
- If all the above steps succeeded it changes the 'current' symlink to /releases// folder.
- It performs an 'apache2ctl graceful' to flush any caches (such as php's realpath() ) that are still caching the previous release.
- If more than a certain number of releases are stored, the oldest one is purged.

The webserver is configured so the docroot of the virtual host points at the 'current' symlink, so during the deployment the old site is visible, and after successful deployment the new site appears instantly.

Code is owned by deploy:deploy but customer-data directories are owned by deploy:upload *and* have their SGID bit set at creation.

Apache's www-data user is a member of groups 'deploy' and 'upload'. Developers have personal scp accounts on the server and are members of group 'upload'. This setup works very well for us, since developers can't interact with the code except via Webistrano. It prevents 'live quickfixes' except by admins and has reduced accidents tremendously. Webistrano's built-in rollback feature makes it quick to revert a faulty deployment.

Developers are given write access to the customer-data dirs (because of the upload group), so they can upload placeholder content or help the customer prefill the site. After all, no customer content is stored in svn. The SGID bit on the directories make sure that only the user ownership of uploaded files is set to the user doing the uploading (providing a bit of accountability). The group ownership remains set to 'upload' by the SGID, so that Apache or other developers can still read-write the files and directories created.

The clear Webistrano interface has proven very useful, and since Capistrano comes with most of the above functionality built-in, our deployment recipes are only two dozen lines. Most of that is overriding Ruby-on-Rails specific defaults.

Comment: I'm using Webistrano but the project has been slowly sinking, no new commit in 10 months. Do you still use Webistrano and if not, can you tell us what you use now ?

Comment: Shadok, we still use Webistrano. I'm a bit worried about the stagnation. Pull requests are not being accepted, etc. I've recently cloned its Git repo on GitHub and added some of our few customizations. This should allow us to keep using it as long as our needs don't change. I look forward to suggestions about similar products though. Webistrano was just what we needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can reconsider the workflow this way :

- Every people is able to commit to the SVN server AND instead of playing with apache rights, create a user on the production server and add a SFTP server.
- Everyone work on their files, and when the commit to the SVN server is done, they use their SFTP client to put in production their files.(Because the'll all use the same user you won't bother with rights)

Actually, before putting in production, you should have an extra server for pre-production.
Before every commit to the production server, they'll add their files to the pre-production server which must be ideally the exact replication of the production server.
When changes are validated, they can put in production the files.